# Парсер строки с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка

```
string str = "0,5(1);1(1);0(2)";
```

Мне необходимо получить цифры, которые стоят `перед скобками` и загнать их в массив. Делаю это так:

```
string str = "0,5(1);1(1);0(2)";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(\(\d\))");
var result = rgx.Replace(str, "").Split(';'); //"0,5(1);1(1);0(2)"->"0,5;1;0"->{"0,5","1","0"}
```

**1. Если есть более оптимальный способ то прошу показать, поскольку за раз таких строк придется обработать минимум `30 000`.**

**2. Теперь необходимо уже наоборот - получить в массив цифры которые стоят `в скобках`. Как это реализовать?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поступите проще:

```
string str = "0,5(1);1(1);0(2)";
string[] numbers = str.Split(new[] { '(', ')', ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

В массиве `numbers` на местах с четными индексами (0, 2, 4, ...) будут числа перед скобками, на нечетных - те, что в скобках:

```
[0]: 0,5
[1]: 1
[2]: 1
[3]: 1
[4]: 0
[5]: 2
```